# Why is subquery and join so slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I need to select rows from BUNDLES table which have one of several SAP_STATE_ID values. Those values depends on whether respective SAP status is supposed to be exported or not.

This query runs really fast (there is index on SAP_STATE_ID field) -

```
SELECT b.* FROM BUNDLES b WHERE b.SAP_STATE_ID IN (2,3,5,6)
```

But... I'd like to fetch list of IDs dynamically, like this:

```
SELECT b.* FROM BUNDLES b 
WHERE b.SAP_STATE_ID IN 
(SELECT s.SAP_STATE_ID FROM SAP_STATES s WHERE s.EXPORT_TO_SAP = 1)
```

And ouch, this query is suddenly taking too much time. I would expect SQL server to run the subquery first (it doesn't depend on anything from main query) and then run whole thing just like in my first example. I tried to rewrite it to use joins instead of subquery:

```
SELECT b.* FROM BUNDLES b 
JOIN SAP_STATES s ON (s.SAP_STATE_ID = b.SAP_STATE_ID) 
WHERE s.EXPORT_TO_SAP = 1
```

but it has same poor performance. It seems like it is running the subquery for each row of BUNDLES table or something like this. I am not very skilled in reading execution plans, but I tried. It says that 81% cost is for scanning Primary key index of BUNDLES (I have no idea why it should do such a thing, there is BUNDLE_ID field defined as PRIMARY KEY, but it doesn't appear in the query at all...)

Does anyone have an explanation why is SQL server so "stupid"? Is there a way to achieve what I want with good performance but without the need to provide static list of SAP_STATE_IDs?

script for both tables and relevant indexes - http://mab.to/xbYiI0wKj

execution plan for subquery version -  http://mab.to/8Qh6gpdYZ

query plan for version with joins - http://mab.to/YCqeGCUbr

(for some reason these two plans looks the same and both suggest creating BUNDLES.SAP_STATE_ID index, which is already there)

Comment: Do you have an index on SAP_STATES.SAP_STATE_ID?

Comment: yes, it is a primary key actually

Comment: How long does the subquery take to run on it's own?

Comment: Oh my bad, it's pretty obvious actually. How about on EXPORT_TO_SAP?

Comment: yes, there is an index as well. But SAP_STATES table has only about  dozen of records in it, so I don't think it matters.

Comment: @DavidG This is table is really small (10-15 records) and also there is index on EXPORT_TO_SAP column. Subquery takes practically zero time.

Comment: It might be helpful to post the schema with index definitions.

Comment: Could you save the query plan as a .sqlplan file and share with us?

Comment: get sql execution plan here - http://mab.to/8Qh6gpdYZ

Comment: I exported script for creating both tables and relevant indexes - http://mab.to/xbYiI0wKj

Comment: It estimates 2,406,720 rows will be returned from the `SELECT` and so uses a CI scan rather than the non covering index and lookups. . I presume that actually it is much less rows?

Comment: BUNDLES table is indeed very large (approx. 18milion records), but actual result of the query is usually very small (zero to one hundred records)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure your statistics are off on the tables. If you want to get it working in a hurry I would write the query as:

```
SELECT b.*
  FROM SAP_STATES s 
 INNER LOOP JOIN BUNDLES b 
    ON s.SAP_STATE_ID = b.SAP_STATE_ID
 WHERE s.EXPORT_TO_SAP = 1
```

This forces a nested loops join over `SAP_STATES` which filters on `BUNDLES`

Comment: yes, this did the trick. I am ashamed that I've never heard about such an option before. I have to learn more about this LOOP thing.

Comment: do I undestand it right that creating proper statistics should make optimizer choose right join type and thus LOOP keyword wouldn't be needed here?

Comment: Indeed. I'm pretty sure that if you run your query with show plan on that you will see the estimated and effective number of returned rows to be very different. Usually updating statistics will be sufficient to resolve the problem. In some cases you need to do more exotic things such as "optimize for unknown", but I don't think this is needed here.

Answer (score 2):

When you use tables(temporary or physical), the SQL engine builds statistics against it and thus has a very clear idea on the number of rows in it and which is the best execution approach for it. On the other hand, a computed table(sub query) doesn't have statistics against it.

So while it might be seemingly simple for a human to deduce the number of rows in it, the "stupid" SQL Engine is unaware of all this. Now, coming to the query, the `WHERE s.EXPORT_TO_SAP = 1` clause is making a world of difference here. The clustered index is sorted and built on the SAP_STATE_ID, but to additionally check the WHERE clause, it has no option but to scan the entire table(in the final dataset)! I bet that if instead of a clustered index, if there was a non clustered covered index on SAP_STATE_ID column which covered the EXPORT_TO_SAP field, it might have done the trick. Since clustered index scans are generally bad for performance, I would suggest you to take the below approach:

```
SELECT s.SAP_STATE_ID 
into #Sap_State
FROM SAP_STATES s WHERE s.EXPORT_TO_SAP = 1

SELECT b.* FROM BUNDLES b 
join #Sap_State a on a.sap_state_id = b.sap_state_id
```

Comment: yes, this approach improves performance, I upvote. But using temporary table feels little strange to me in this case. To be 100% clean, there should also be DROP TABLE #Sap_state after the select. Thus we made original one-liner into three lines, which I am not happy about very much.

Comment: BTW, why this approach works and others don't? I don't understand why having values in temporary table is faster than having them in a recordset which came as result of subquery. Is it only about the optimizer that doesn't build proper execution plan in other cases?

Comment: Edited my answer with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Since for some reason having problems going to mab.to,

I would suggest ensure the following

```
table        index
sap_states   (export_to_sap, sap_state_id )
bundles      (sap_state_id)

select
      b.*
   from 
      sap_states ss
         join bundles b
            on ss.sap_state_id = b.sap_state_id
   where 
      ss.export_to_sap = 1
```

Comment: I tried to rewrite the query using JOINs (as described in the question), but with no success. Your query has only swapped order of bundles and sap_states tables - I tried this and it remains the same.

Comment: Did you create an index on `bundles.sap_state_id`? Also, post the explain plan for your query using a join.